# error NG8001 in angular even after importing shared module in other modules and exporting components in shared module

Tags: angular, angular14

error NG8001 in angular even after importing shared module in other modules and exporting components in shared module

Error I am getting:

```
Error: src/app/public/home/home.component.html:3:1 - error NG8001: 'app-footer' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-footer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-footer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the 
'@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

3 <app-footer></app-footer>
~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/public/home/home.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component HomeComponent.
```

I created a shared module. Inside that I have header and footer component.In shared module.ts, under declaration and exports array I mentioned the header and footer components. In public module.ts file, in imports array, mentioned the shared module but then also getting error. Just wanted to know, is shared module no longer supported in angular 14?

Shared module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
 HeaderComponent,
 FooterComponent
],
imports: [
],
exports:[
 HeaderComponent,
 FooterComponent
]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Public module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { PublicRoutingModule } from './public-routing.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { PublicComponent } from './public.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
 HomeComponent,
 PublicComponent
],
imports: [
 CommonModule,
 PublicRoutingModule,
 SharedModule
]
})
export class PublicModule { }
```

In home component.html which is under public module

```
<p>home works!</p>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Most important thing in vscode no problems showing but I am running using cmd there errors are showing

Footer component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-footer',
templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./footer.component.css']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

ngOnInit(): void {
}

}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample project on https://stackblitz.com/? So, We can check the problem to solve it together.

Comment: let me share u the github link

Comment: https://github.com/ganeshapmb/Angular14

Comment: oke, let me check

Comment: I get the problem, the problem is you are not correct to import the home component. You are calling the home component in-app routing.module but you registered that component public.module.ts. Let me fork your project and I will make a pull request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I've made a pull request here, check this link below
https://github.com/ganeshapmb/Angular14/pull/1

Answer (score 0):

*app.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    // Add here: PublicModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*public.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    PublicComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PublicRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ]
})
export class PublicModule { }
```

You are importing `HomeComponent` in `PublicModule` but the `AppModule` (your root module) doesn't know that `PublicModule` exists because you don't import `SharedModule` in `AppModule`. And then, it doesn't matter that you have imported `SharedModule` in `PublicModule` where the `HomeComponent` is imported/exported.
I would really recommend to improve your folder/component/module structure because like this, it is very confusing.

But to answer your question: Import `PublicModule` in `AppModule` and it will work.